# In Visual Studio code, if I'm in the search widget, how do I make the escape key give editor focus WITHOUT closing the widget?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

[image]

Is there a way to modify the shortcuts so pressing `escape` in the find widget (the red dot) gives the editor (the green dot) focus without closing the find widget?

I've done a little research on my own, and I think I'll have to make two changes for this:

1. I will have to add `escape` to a shortcut that gives the editor focus. I've found one that does this, named `View: Focus Active Editor Group`. There is probably a better fitting shortcut I could be using instead, and I'd like to know what it is.
2. I will have to remove the shortcut that closes the search widget when it has focus and you press the `escape` key.

I'm completely lost on that second point. There's a shortcut called `Search: Cancel Search` which seems like the obvious choice, but it's "when" column suggests otherwise: `listFocus && searchViewletVisible && !inputFocus && searchState != '0'`

First of all, I don't know what `listFocus` means, and [the official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts) doesn't explain. Second, `!inputFocus` does not seem like the scenario I'm trying to change.

Third, it's nontrivial to search for the `escape` key shortcuts, since it closes the search dialog. Fortunately, I figured out that this can be done by *typing* `"escape"` into the keyboard shortcut search. I'm providing this information to others because they may need to know this to help me.

---

If I press escape in the search widget, the [keyboard debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_troubleshooting-keybindings) says:

```
[2022-05-06 04:03:00.883] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [], code: Escape, keyCode: 27, key: Escape
[2022-05-06 04:03:00.883] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [], code: Escape, keyCode: 9 ('Escape')
[2022-05-06 04:03:00.883] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving Escape
[2022-05-06 04:03:00.883] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 52 keybinding entries, matched closeFindWidget, when: editorFocus && findWidgetVisible && !isComposing, source: built-in.
```

Comment: `Search: Cancel Search` looks like an escape for when you have the Search Bar open and are searching in files.

Comment: @rioV8 I thought it might be that,  but I didn't understand why it would *expect* `listFocus` and `!inputFocus` if that were the case

Comment: `inputFocus` is when you have an input box like QuickPick or InputBox at the top, if you have a list with focus, like explorer, it is `listFocus` I think

Comment: instead of `Esc` you can always use `Ctrl+1` or `Ctrl+2`,..., `Ctrl+9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define this in your `keybindings.json`

The last key binding that matches the key and `when` is used (search is done from the bottom)

```
{ "key": "escape",
  "command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
  "when": "findInputFocussed && editorFocus || replaceInputFocussed && editorFocus"
}
```

The `when` clause looks weird but that is because you cant use `()`.

Comment: okay since I can't use `()`, what is this saying? `(editorTextFocus && findInputFocussed) || (editorTextFocus && replaceInputFocussed)`? Also, is `Focussed` a typo?

Comment: @DanielKaplan If the focus is in one of the find dialog input boxes the `when` clause is True. no typo, that is the context variable as used in the default key bindings, yes `&&` has higher priority than `||`, they first split the string on `||`

Comment: I put that at the bottom of my `keybindings,json` [sic], but when I press escape, it still closes the widget

Comment: @DanielKaplan have you tried the [keybinding debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_troubleshooting-keybindings) to see if this keybinding is choosen

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I updated my original post but I know what my next step will be.

Comment: @DanielKaplan see my edit, I have it working, I used a when from the standard bindings but you can't have focus in the editor AND in the findInput, maybe `editorFocus` is better, `editorTextFocus` is false if cursor in find dialog, I checked, I have read it wrong from the keybind GUI, you can't copy paste when clauses

Comment: Is `findWidgetVisible ` adding anything to the `when` clause?  Will it not always be true if `findInputFocussed || replaceInputFocussed` is true?

Comment: @Mark yes, I have modified the answer to use a `when` similar to the default bindings