How to switch focus from find box back to editor panel in VS Code?
In VS Code, what is the keyboard shortcut to switch back to the editor from the find box opened by ctrl-f ?
I have searched the internet for various variations on the above, but all I got were answers to press ctrl-`
and ctrl-tab twice which seems sub optimal and kind of a hack.
And pressing esc closes the find box which is what I definitely do not want.

The linked question is very relevant and useful, but not a duplicate. If someone posted focusActiveEditorGroup as an answer here, i'd upvote it :)

@wjandrea I would love the upvote but it looks like an exact duplicate to me.  How to  shift focus to the editor without closing the Find widget.  Am I missing something?

@Mark The linked question is specifically about the Escape key.

@wjandrea Good point.  I have re-opened the question and undeleted my answer.

I definitely did not want to rebind the esc to change its behaviour.  Thank you for reopening and answering my question :).  For reference, this is the link to Q&A about the esc key: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72139122/in-visual-studio-code-if-im-in-the-search-widget-how-do-i-make-the-escape-key

Add a keybinding to focus the active editor group, which is what you want to do.
Find this command in the Keyboard Shortcuts editor, hover over it and click the + sign to its left and enter your desired keyboard shortcut into the dialog box.
View: Focus Active Editor Group
workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup


You can press Ctrl+Down, which runs the command scrollLineDown and leaves the find box. I assume the equivalent on Mac is Cmd+Down.
